# Why can my VMware Win8 guest system not paste from Chromium's clipboard when it works for all other applications?

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-machine, vmware, clipboard, chromium

I am running a Win8.1 guest in VMware Player 6.03 on an Ubuntu 14.04 host system. The Win 8.1 virtual machine can access text copied from Firefox, gedit, gnome-terminal and other applications, but not from Chromium. The text can be copied either via ^C our mouse middle click, both elicit the same behaviour. Text copied from the virtual machine can be pasted into any application on the host, via both clipboards.

Is Chromium's clipboard somehow special or is there any other reason to why this is not working?

**Edit:** Just noticed that PDFXchange running on Ubuntu host through wine behaves the same way as Chromium. I can't paste anything into the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to some bug and reported already:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395077

As a workaround to the present situation, please copy the text content to a text editor, then again copy it from the text editor to the virtual machine. It should work this way.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, thanks for linking that bug report. Didn't pop up in my own searching.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use xsel:

```
xsel -ob|xsel -ib
```

Check out this [gist](https://gist.github.com/qq1/048945b595aab22c165f).

Comment: thanks, I can't check this out at the moment as I do not have my virtual machine anymore, but ill remember it for later.